# leaflet does not work with babel package?

Tags: babel, leaflet

Is leaflet package incompatible with babel package?

This code does not work

```
    \documentclass[foldmark,10pt,a4paper,notumble]{leaflet}
    \usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[greek]{babel}
    \begin{document}
       Όμορφος κόσμος ηθικός αγγελικά πλασμένος
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not `babel` itself but option `greek` is the problem. It redefines `\@Roman` to have roman numbers always in Latin letters. But unfortunately `leaflet` uses `\Roman` (and so `\@Roman`) internally very often and sometimes it breaks.

If you do not need roman numbers, you can try:

```
\documentclass[foldmark,10pt,a4paper,notumble]{leaflet}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\let\OrigRoman\@Roman
\makeatother
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\makeatletter
\let\@Roman\OrigRoman
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Όμορφος κόσμος ηθικός αγγελικά πλασμένος
\end{document}
```

If you need roman numbers, you can try to use `xpatch` to patch the `leaflet` macros:

```
\documentclass[foldmark,10pt,a4paper,notumble]{leaflet}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\let\Orig@Roman\@Roman
\newcommand*{\OrigRoman}[1]{\expandafter\Orig@Roman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\LL@AddToBackground}{\@Roman}{\Orig@Roman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\LL@AddToBackground}{\@Roman}{\Orig@Roman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\LL@savePage}{\Roman}{\OrigRoman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\LL@savePage}{\Roman}{\OrigRoman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\LL@savePage}{\Roman}{\OrigRoman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\LL@savePage}{\Roman}{\OrigRoman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\LL@savePage}{\Roman}{\OrigRoman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@@end}{\@Roman}{\Orig@Roman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@@end}{\@Roman}{\Orig@Roman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@@end}{\@Roman}{\Orig@Roman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@@end}{\@Roman}{\Orig@Roman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@@end}{\Roman}{\OrigRoman}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Όμορφος κόσμος ηθικός αγγελικά πλασμένος
\end{document}
```

[image: the leadlet]

Note: I do not know whether or not this could result in other problems. Because I did not examined the `leaflet` code in detail.

Comment: I' ve checked both and works perfect. The second way needs \usepackage{enumitem}   
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)] Thank you anyway